# How to Display Output in Text Area in java

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am trying to display my output in Jtext Area.

```
while ((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {
    txt_output.append(line1+"\n");
    System.out.println(line1);
}
```

It gives me output once all the process finished. What want to show output execution line by line instead of all together.

please help me.....

Comment: are you saying your console gets updated in the process and JTextArea not?

Comment: I am getting output in Jtextarea.My requirement is i want line by line  output. Above lines gives me complete output once all finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One similar post in Stackoverflow, deals with concurrency using threads.

Refer this one: [Dynamically refresh JTextArea as processing occurs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629315/dynamically-refresh-jtextarea-as-processing-occurs)

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use the

```
textArea.setText();
```

method every time when you want the message to be printed.
It automatically removes the previous text and writes the new one.

Comment: Hi this is giving Only Last output i want all the output.

Comment: The following method is very bad practice but you can try it for now
int temp = 0;
while ((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {
    if(temp==0){
       txt_output.append(line1+"\n");
       temp = 1;
     }
     if(temp==1) {
      System.out.println(line1);
    temp = 0;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I know the following method is very bad practice but you can try it for now

```
int temp = 0;
while ((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {
if(temp==0){
   txt_output.append(line1+"\n");
   temp = 1;
 }
 if(temp==1) {
  System.out.println(line1);
temp = 0;
}
}
```