# append text in jtextarea continuosuly?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, loops, jtextarea

i've following code in my program (slightly different)

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= 100000; j++)
    {
        // some code here
        jtxtArea.append("some text here");
    }
}
```

I want to append some text in jtextarea with each iteration of inner loop. but problem is the text is appended at once when execution leaves out the loop. I want to append text as loop continues. If I use `System.out.println("some text here");` instead of `jtxtArea.append("some text here");` it works the way I want (text is appended to console as loops are executed). can anyone give me some clue so that I can get same effect with `jtxtarea`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically refresh JTextArea as processing occurs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629315/dynamically-refresh-jtextarea-as-processing-occurs)

Comment: You want to run the operation in a separate thread instead of using the same thread that is running your application's messaging loop. The link provided by Ascalonian outlines how to do this.